Run-time error “‘-2147352571(80020005)‘”: Type Mismatch, but only on one pc
I have this small piece of code, which happens on initialization of an userform
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Holddata")


lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "V").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Me.CostcenterBox.AddItem ws.Cells(i, "V").Value
Next i

Me.DatoBox.Value = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")

Me.StartUpPosition = 0
Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Me.Width)
Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Me.Height)

End Sub

This code has worked for three users in almost a year and is still working, when they press the button which runs the following macro
Sub NewPost()

AddPost.Show

End Sub

Recently we hired a new colleague, who also need to use the userform, but she gets an "Run-time error “‘-2147352571(80020005)‘”: Type Mismatch", when she presses the button, instead of the userform as the others.
My googling has told me, that it could be a problem with the "Date" function, but i'm confused to why it's only a problem for 1 of 4 people.
Do anyone have any idea, what could be happening?
Best Regards,
Mikki

Which line throws the error?

Hint: If you don't see line of error: Go to the VBA environment, Tools->Option, switch to the General Tab and activate "Break in class modules". I can imagine that the problem is the line AddItem ws.Cells(i, "V").Value, one of the cells contain an invalid value (like an error)

Check the Locale settings for that user compared to the others
